# Principia Mathematica and Law of Gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, history

Could anyone, please, point the exact place in "Principia Mathematica" where Newton explicitly stated the expression for the gravitational force between two particles? I mean the fact that it is proportional to the product of their masses and the inverse square of the distance between them. The closest thing I've found is Propositional 75, Theorem 35, Corollary 1 [Isaac Newton, The Principia: Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy. Preceded by A Guide to Newton's Principia, by I.Bernard Cohen. University of California Press 1999]:

*"The attractions of spheres toward other homogeneous spheres are as the attracting spheres [i.e., as the masses of the attracting spheres] divided by the squares of the distances of their own centers from the centers of those that they attract."*

But this statement is about spheres, not particles. And also only about the proportionality to the mass of the attracting sphere, not the attracted one. So, is the law present in the general from in this book?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It would be impossible for Newton to prove this proposition about homogeneous spheres without assuming the force between the particles that make up the spheres. So that has to appear earlier.

Comment: @Miyase Sorry, I didn't know about this site. I've posted the question there.

Comment: @Ghoster Sure, but somehow I did not manage to find it. He speaks a lot about the inverse square proportionality, indeed, but I could not find the explicit statement about the masses.

Comment: Maybe it’s an implicit assumption that Newton considered obvious. You shouldn’t assume that what we consider good exposition today was the standard in Newton’s day.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belons to history of science